# Prove that if $\text{Ran}(R) \subseteq \text{Dom}(S)$, then $\text{Dom}(S \circ R) = \text{Dom}(R)$

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

> **Proposition.** If $\text{Ran}(R) \subseteq \text{Dom}(S)$, then $\text{Dom}(S \circ R) = \text{Dom}(R)$

My attempt:

Suppose $\text{Ran}(R) \subseteq \text{Dom}(S)$

We need to show:

$(\rightarrow) $   $\text{Dom}(S \circ R) \subseteq \text{Dom}(R)$

$(\leftarrow)$ $\text{Dom}(R) \subseteq \text{Dom}(S \circ R) $

---

$(\rightarrow)$

Consider arbitrary element $a$, where $a \in \text{Dom}(S \circ R)$. Then there must be some element $p$, where $p = (a,x)$ and $p \in R$. It implies that $a \in Dom(R)$. Since $a$ was arbitrary, we have $\text{Dom}(S \circ R) \subseteq \text{Dom}(R)$

$(\leftarrow$)

Consider element $(x,y)$ where $(x,y) \in R$. Since $y \in Ran(R)$ and  $\text{Ran}(R) \subseteq \text{Dom}(S)$, it follows that $y \in Dom(S)$, which means that there must be some element $(y,p)$ such that $(y,p) \in S$.

Since $(y,p) \in S$ and $(x,y) \in R$, we have $(x,p) \in S \circ R$, and it means that $x \in Dom(S \circ R)$.

Since we've considered arbitrary element, we have $\text{Dom}(R) \subseteq \text{Dom}(S \circ R)$

We've shown both sides, hence $\text{Dom}(S \circ R) = \text{Dom}(R)$. $\Box$

---

Is it correct?

If it is, are there better ways to prove $(\rightarrow)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof is correct.

Further I don't think that there is a better way to prove $(\rightarrow)$.

I invite you to compare with how I did it (no essential differences).

---

$(\rightarrow) $   $\text{Dom}(S \circ R) \subseteq \text{Dom}(R)$

Let $x\in\mathsf{Dom}\left(S\circ R\right)$.

Then (by definition of $S\circ R$) some $y$ and some $z$ must exist
with $\left(x,y\right)\in R$ and $\left(y,z\right)\in S$.

From $\left(x,y\right)\in R$ it follows directly that $x\in\mathsf{Dom}\left(R\right)$.

$(\leftarrow)$ $\text{Dom}(R) \subseteq \text{Dom}(S \circ R) $

Let $x\in\mathsf{Dom}\left(R\right)$.

Then $\left(x,y\right)\in R$
for some $y\in\mathsf{Ran}\left(R\right)\subseteq\mathsf{Dom}\left(S\right)$.

Then $\left(y,z\right)\in S$ for some $z$ and this together tells
us that $\left(x,z\right)\in S\circ R$, hence $x\in\mathsf{Dom}\left(S\circ R\right)$.

Answer (score 0):

In the proof of your forward direction, you say "It implies that $a\in Dom(T)$. Try to be specific about what "it" is. Why does this mean that $a\in Dom(S\circ R)$? You should properly show why $a$ is a possible input for the function $S\circ R$. In a more simplistic notation, if $$R(a)$ exists, does $S(R(a))$ exist, and why?

Your proof of the backwards directions seems great!